# can I filter TCP SYN packets with seq=0

Tags: tcp, ddos

My servers appear to be targeted by a SYN-flood attack. Between 50-600MBit/s, spoofed IPs.

Packets look like this:

```
IP p.q.r.s.1234 > my.ser.vers.ip.80: Flags [S], seq 0, win 5840, length 0
```

with `p.q.r.s` apparently being random. (yes, source port is always 1234)

While this alone is not enough to fill my link, the responses play their part as well and the machines becomes pretty slow.

Is it reasonable to drop TCP SYNs with seq=0?

Comment: Why not drop when the source port is `1234`?  We saw a DDoS with exactly the same characteristics and that worked for us.  The same DDoS had randomised ports earlier so it may not be a permanent solution.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I figured, though, it would lead to more false positives and (for some reason) assumed the DDoSer's tool would probably allow him to change the port but not the seqno...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can drop TCP SYNs with seq=0, you'll only have a 1/4294967296 chance (more or less) or dropping a real connection.... **BUT**:

**The actual TCP sequence number is probably not 0!**

I don't know what tool you're using (the output format does not quite seem to match either `tcpdump` or `tshark`/Wireshark) but both `tcpdump` and Wireshark actually remember state of TCP streams and subtract the initial sequence number from the value displayed in both `seq` and `ack` fields, so that 0 means "whatever the ISN was".

Note this option from the `tcpdump` manpage:

> ```
>    -S     Print absolute, rather than relative, TCP sequence numbers.
> ```

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, forgot to mention: this was tcpdump and every other connection had non-zero seqnos, so I assumed it was giving absolutes. Will investigate as soon as I get another attack, thank you!